# How can I unit test templates that accompany components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I understand that we're supposed to test component controllers using $componentController, but how can we test the templates that accompany the component? It has been very straightforward with directives, and I assume it'd be as easy with components. I could not find an answer in the docs, nor elsewhere. Here's an example.

Having a component with template like this:

```
<div ng-click="vm.doSomething();">
  Click me
</div>
```

I'd like to programmatically trigger the click in a test, and verify that whatever vm.doSomething() - a method of our component's controller - was supposed to do, it did it correctly. **How can I do that?**

Comment: I think that most programmers consider unit tests covering the controller methods to be adequate. I personally don't test template click events. Could be wrong.

Comment: While that's certainly enough in many cases, I wasn't able to do it at all, hence my question.

Comment: _"It has been very straightforward with directives"_ A component is a directive ...

Comment: take string <my-component></my-component>, compile it. Trigger events.